# How do I access a web page and change content mysql - phpmyadmin - ftp

Tags: php, html, web, phpmyadmin, ftp

I have access to mysql database on phpmyadmin and ftp serves, where I have 3 folder : wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes.

On the website I want to change some basic information, but
almost all files have a extension .php. But i dont se something similar like index.html

I'm old school for websites and I don't know this website composition, please help or guide what I need to do to get to basic editing

please help me.

Comment: it looks like you are using wordpress, which is written in php. if you want to write whole website yourself in html, you need to uninstall wordpress first. otherwise you need to have good understanding of php

Comment: So who gave you access to the site and who made it? Why not ask them? It seems to be built in Wordpress (a CMS written in PHP) so you need to do some proper research and learn how it works. There are many getting starting guides about both PHP and Wordpress out there. That's way too much for us to cover here, and asking for suggestions/recommendations about tutorials etc are off-topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how can I uninstall wordpress  ? i want to change some basic settings on the website and some personal information on the website. The problem is because the website is composed unknown to me.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is an acronym for "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor" · PHP is a widely-used, open source scripting language. open your php file as you would your .html file, your html code is contained within the file.

Comment: This is really a simplification. They seem to be using Wordpress and editing Wordpress sites are a little bit more complicated. If you want to edit the content, you should leave the php-files alone and use their admin. If you're going to edit the layout (html/css), you need to understand how their templates work and what files to open.